# PolynomialReduce inconsistent results

Tags: polynomials, algebra, groebner-bases

I was playing around with gröbner basis and s-polynomials and I fell upon the PolynomialReduce, and I was wondering why it gives different results when I move around the polynomials in its second parameter,

```
PolynomialReduce[x^2 (x^2 + y) - 1 (x^2 y + 1), {x^2 y + 1, y + x^2, x^4 - 1}, {x, y}]
```

gives

```
{{-1, x^2, 0}, 0}
```

while

```
PolynomialReduce[ x^2 (x^2 + y) - 1 (x^2 y + 1), {y + x^2, x^2 y + 1, x^4 - 1}, {x, y}]
```

gives

```
{{x^2 - y, 0, 0}, -1 + y^2}
```

which is obviously wrong** as it is very apparent that the coefficients is just x^2 and -1.

Can anybody shed some light on this? It's very disturbing and confusing.

[edit]
**the result might not be wrong, but it does not give the minimal b as per instruced by the documentation
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the only thing that PolynomialReduce guarantees is that

p[x,y]= c1 b1[x,y] + c2 b2[x,y] + ... + cn bn[x,y] + r

where {{c1,c2,...,cn},r} is the result of polynomial reduce, as it is for your example.

Not that the result is in any way minimal or unique.  In your example p[x,y] = x^4 - 1, so in fact the 'best' result would be {{0,0,1},0}, but this is only obtained when x^4 -1 is the first polynomial.

I am quite sure that result of general polynomial division is not unique unless over a (reduced) Groebner basis.  The Groebner basis for the ideal generated by your two polynomial sets are, of course, the same.

Comment: (John I'm sure knows this but...) just to chime in, this response is correct in every detail.

Comment: An additional though: in the linear algebra case if v, u1, u2 are vectors in Rn then projecting v onto u1, then projecting (v - proj(v,u1)) onto u2 will also give a different result than projecting onto u2 first, unless u1,u2 are orthogonal.

Comment: But the specification
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html
Actually guarantees that 'b is minimal' ?

Comment: Yes, for a suitable definition of "minimal". It simply means that `b` cannot be further reduced by the list of polynomials. For "canonical" you need to first create a Groebner basis, per this response.

Comment: Can you explain why I am getting the following results then when I am reducing it to a groebner basis?
`gb := GroebnerBasis[{y + x^2, x^2 y + 1, x^4 - 1}, {y, x}]
PolynomialReduce[x^2 (x^2 + y) - 1 (x^2 y + 1), gb, {y, x}]
(*gives result*)
{{1, 0}, 0}`
Now these are just not correct in any sense.

Comment: (1) You are more likely to get a response if I am aware of your comment to effect that use @Daniel Lichtblau in yours since it will not otherwise show up in my MSE notification. (2) You are reducing `x^2 (x^2 + y) - 1 (x^2 y + 1)` which expands to `x^4-1`. the first polynomial in gb is `x^4-1`. So the result is just as expected.